# CosmosDB $sample aggregation delivers always the same result

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, sample

i'm a newbie in Mongo and Cosmos DB. I'm trying to get some random values from one collection with the following aggregation query, but it delivers repeatedly same result:

```
db.jokes.aggregate(
     [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
  )
Operation consumed 2.39 RUs
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1526501e39b24ccc50d369"),
    "joke" : "Giraffes are born or created when Chuck Norris uppercuts a Horse!",
    "language" : "en"
}
 db.jokes.aggregate(
     [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
  )
Operation consumed 2.39 RUs
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1526501e39b24ccc50d369"),
    "joke" : "Giraffes are born or created when Chuck Norris uppercuts a Horse!",
    "language" : "en"
}
```

Am i doing something wrong or it is a bug in an aggregation feature of CosmosDB?

Many thanks and regards,

Gena

Comment: Your query is correct and the `$sample` feature is supported: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20100751-allow-for-random-sample Mind you, if you only have a handful of documents in your collection then the same document might get picked twice by `$sample`.

Comment: Ich think, there are about 5000 documents, but $sample delivers always the same set for same size.

Comment: "You think" or you know? ;)

Comment: `db.jokes.count()
Operation consumed 1 RUs
22081`